# google cloud function deploying failed functions: cleaning up build files

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

when i tried to deployed the cloud functions. i am facing the error below..

[image]

before update the node version it was working fine

node@14
firebase cli up-to date
nom also up-to date

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp()
exports.sendcertificate = functions.firestore.document('certificate/{docId}')
.onCreate((snap: { data: () => any; }, ctx: any) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    let authData = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mail.bacttraining.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // use SSL
        auth: {
            user: *******',
            pass: *******',
        },
    });
    authData.sendMail({
        from: ********,
        to: *********,
        Bcc: '*******',
        sender: "*******",
        subject: "Certificate Request",
        text: `${data.course}`,
        html: *******,
    }).then(console.log("email send sussfully"))
        .catch(console.error('we cant send email : ', console.error()
        ));
    }

   );**strong text**
```

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hey how did you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CLI tools are up to date, and that your modules in use are the latest. I can see that the console is warning you that cloud functions are outdated.
Then ensure all functions that did not deploy for any bugs and syntax errors as the cloud functions uploader can crash if the code was packed incorrectly.

Once the above has been done, you can try deploying the functions **one** at a time with

- `firebase deploy --only functions:functionName`

This will narrow any functions that have bugs or syntax errors down.

Comment: thank u for your comment but it not work with me

Comment: there must be a bug somewhere in your code that is not presented - could even be missing/not installed modules

Comment: @mewish were you able to solve the issue I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when there is difference in the **node version** you have installed in the system and the node engine version mentioned in `package.json` file.

Please check your node version using

```
node -v
```

[image: node version]

Make sure you have mentioned the same engine version in `package.json`

[image]